# In iOS, could you use an NSDictionary as a text file?

Tags: ios, ipad, nsdictionary, outline

For an outline-style note-taking app, couldn't each line be saved in an NSDictionary and the indent and label (I., II...; A., B...; 1., 2...) be the key? A custom view could be created to organize it all. Would that be possible, and would it be efficient? The dictionary would be a property of a custom subclass of UIDocument. Would bold, italic, underline, special characters, and font sizes/fonts be editable then?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference you would find is that UIDocuments will store information on a file somewhere on the iOS device, On the other hand, NSDictionaries don't do this, they hold everything in memory.

So using the documents would ensure that the data can be restored. But if you use an NSDictionary then as soon as that dictionary is deallocated (Say your program crashes, or you move onto a different view.) Then you'd lose all your information.

If you're expecting any sort of persistence to the information stored, you're going to have to go with UIDocuments or find another way to store the data.

Comment: So you couldn't have the NSDictionary as a property of the UIDocument?

Comment: Well, if you were wanting to store everything in an NSDictionary, instead of going through the UIDocument I would look into the NSDictionary functions for writing a dictionary to a file (`writeToFile:atomically`), and reading from an NSDictionary from a file (`dictionaryWithContentsOfFile`).

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary idea is going to hurt you when you need to re-order the outline.  I would just store everything in an array.  Each object in the array is either a string or another array.  Each time you find an array, that means you indent a level.

So if you had array objects like this:

```
[0]  @"something"
[1]  [0]   @"something else"
[2]  @"another thing"
```

You'd display

```
I. Something
   A. something else
II. another thing
```